# Transactional kafka listener retry

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to create a Spring Kafka `@KafkaListener` which is both transactional (kafa and database) and uses retry. I am using Spring Boot. The documentation for error handlers says that

> When transactions are being used, no error handlers are configured, by default, so that the exception will roll back the transaction. Error handling for transactional containers are handled by the AfterRollbackProcessor. If you provide a custom error handler when using transactions, it must throw an exception if you want the transaction rolled back ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handlers)).

However, when I configure my listener with a `@Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager`) annotation, even though I can clearly see that the template rolls back produced messages when an exception is raised, the container actually uses a non-null `commonErrorHandler` rather than an `AfterRollbackProcessor`. This is the case even when I explicitly configure the `commonErrorHandler` to null in the container factory. I do not see any evidence that my configured `AfterRollbackProcessor` is ever invoked, even after the `commonErrorHandler` exhausts its retry policy.

I'm uncertain how Spring Kafka's error handling works in general at this point, and am looking for clarification. The questions I want to answer are:

- What is the recommended way to configure transactional kafka listeners with Spring-Kafka 2.8.0? Have I done it correctly?
- Should the common error handler indeed be used rather than the after rollback processor? Does it rollback the current transaction before trying to process the message again according to the retry policy?
- In general, when I have a transactional kafka listener, is there ever more than one layer of error handling I should be aware of? E.g. if my common error handler re-throws exceptions of kind T, will another handler catch that and potentially start retry of its own?

Thanks!

My code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConfiguration.class);

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory) {
    var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, Object>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);

    var afterRollbackProcessor =
        new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<Object, Object>(
            (record, e) -> LOGGER.info("After rollback processor triggered! {}", e.getMessage()),
            new FixedBackOff(1_000, 1));

    // Configures different error handling for different listeners.
    factory.setContainerCustomizer(
        container -> {
          var groupId = container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId();
          if (groupId.equals("InputProcessorHigh") || groupId.equals("InputProcessorLow")) {
            container.setAfterRollbackProcessor(afterRollbackProcessor);
            // If I set commonErrorHandler to null, it is defaulted instead.
          }
        });
    return factory;
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class InputProcessor {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InputProcessor.class);

  private final KafkaTemplate<Integer, Object> template;
  private final AuditLogRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  public InputProcessor(KafkaTemplate<Integer, Object> template, AuditLogRepository repository) {
    this.template = template;
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @KafkaListener(id = "InputProcessorHigh", topics = "input-high", concurrency = "3")
  @Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")
  public void inputHighProcessor(ConsumerRecord<Integer, Input> input) {
    processInputs(input);
  }

  @KafkaListener(id = "InputProcessorLow", topics = "input-low", concurrency = "1")
  @Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")
  public void inputLowProcessor(ConsumerRecord<Integer, Input> input) {
    processInputs(input);
  }

  public void processInputs(ConsumerRecord<Integer, Input> input) {
    var key = input.key();
    var message = input.value().getMessage();
    var output = new Output().setMessage(message);

    LOGGER.info("Processing {}", message);
    template.send("output-left", key, output);
    repository.createIfNotExists(message); // idempotent insert
    template.send("output-right", key, output);

    if (message.contains("ERROR")) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Simulated processing error!");
    }
  }
}
```

My application.yaml (minus my bootstrap-servers and security config):

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: 'earliest'
      key-deserializer: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer'
      value-deserializer: 'org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer'
      isolation-level: 'read_committed'
      properties:
        spring.json.trusted.packages: 'java.util,java.lang,com.github.tomboyo.silverbroccoli.*'
    producer:
      transaction-id-prefix: 'tx-'
      key-serializer: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer'
      value-serializer: 'org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer'
```

**[EDIT] (solution code)**

I was able to figure it out with Gary's help. As they say, we need to set the kafka transaction manager on the container so that the container can start transactions. The transactions documentation doesn't cover how to do this, and there are a few ways. First, we can get the mutable container properties object from the factory and set the transaction manager on *that*:

```java
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
    var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(...);
    return factory;
}
```

If we are in Spring Boot, we can re-use some of the auto configuration to set sensible defaults on our factory before we customize it. We can see that the `KafkaAutoConfiguration` module imports `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration`, which produces a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` bean. This appears to be responsible for all the default configuration in a Spring-Boot application. So, we can inject that bean and use it to initialize our factory before adding customizations:

```java
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer bootConfigurer,
      ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory) {
    var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>();

    // Apply default spring-boot configuration.
    bootConfigurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory);

    factory.setContainerCustomizer(
        container -> {
          ... // do whatever
        });
    return factory;
  }
```

Once that's done, the container uses the AfterRollbackProcessor for error handling, as expected. As long as I don't explicitly configure a common error handler, this appears to be the only layer of exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AfterRollbackProcessor` is only used when the container knows about the transaction; you must provide a `KafkaTransactionManager` to the container so that the kafka transaction is started by the container, and the offsets sent to the transaction. Using `@Transactional` is not the correct way to start a Kafka Transaction.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: The link no longer shows part of transactions. This one might be more clear https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/transactions.html